# Tabbing on different buttons on the page when scraping Morningstar data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried to use the command below to enable clicking action in the selenium webdriver when I call it from my Python script in order to select one of the 5, 10, 15-year buttons (instead of the 3-year that is selected by default) but it gave me a blank error.
The command I used was

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#yr10mpt"))).click()
```

and the webpage is:

```
performance.morningstar.com/funds/etf/ratings-risk.action?t=VDC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got that one to work with the following.

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='10-Year']")))
for elem in elements:
    elem.click()
```

Comment: It didn't work at my end, the error message: TimeoutException    Traceback (most recent call last)  <ipython-input-1-aa9f612ab965> in <module>
     27 # get web page
     28 driver.get(urlpage)
---> 29 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='10-Year']"))).click()
     wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
          82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Try a larger time from 10.

Comment: Tried all the wy up to 30, every time I get the same final error >>>> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: It works. I previously missed the = in the URL, and I had the options set to not show the driver window when it connects. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There are two tables with tabs on that page, MPT and Volatility Measures, the code only clicks the tab of the first table, but not the second?

Comment: Not the second. Do you need the second?

Comment: Yes please. Thank you

Comment: Solved it: WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "year10vm"))).click()

Comment: Your solution is elegant. Thank you.